# Persistant Facebook User Login using Parse

Tags: ios, facebook, parse-platform

I'm using the Complete iOS 7 course on *Udemy* and am having a problem with Facebook login persistence. I working on the *MatchedUp app*.

When I delete the app from my simulator and login with a test user the original name and profile picture persists.  When checking Parse data it has clearly created the second user, user permissions, and profile picture.  It's not reflected in my app.

- Can someone please point me in the right direction?
- Is there a method that needs to be called to disable parse push?

Here is where I query Photo:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Photo"];
    *//[query whereKey:@"user" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];*
    [query includeKey:kCCPhotoUserKey];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error)
    {
        if (!error)
        {
        self.photos = objects;
        [self queryForCurrentPhotoIndex];
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"%@", error);
        }
    }];
```

and this is where I create Photo:

```
PFFile *photoFile = [PFFile fileWithData:imageData];
    *//PFFile *photoFile = [PFFile fileWithName:[PFUser currentUser][@"user"] data:imageData];*
    [photoFile saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error)
    {
        PFObject *photo = [PFObject objectWithClassName:kCCPhotoClassKey];
        [photo setObject:[PFUser currentUser] forKey:kCCPhotoUserKey];
        [photo setObject:photoFile forKey:kCCPhotoPictureKey];
        [photo saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error)
        {
            NSLog(@"Photo Saved Successfully");
        }];
    }];
```

Comment: Can you provide code where you create the user?

Comment: I've added my code.  The two lines that are commented out is where I've tried things that didn't work.